# Selenium not clicking on second dropdown: TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Overview:
I am new to Selenium and I have the following code that I am trying to run to scrape data from a public website [link](http://registration.telangana.gov.in/ts/UnitRateMV.do?method=getDistrictList&uType=U).This website has three dropdowns(district, mandal and village) which a user has to select to get result for a specific village. For e.g. If you select a district all the mandals in that district will be populated in the mandal dropdown and on selecting a specific mandal from that, all the villages in the mandal will get populated in the village dropdown.

What I want to achieve with this code? I want this code to go to the district dropdown select the first district then go to the mandal dropdown select the first and finally select the first from the village dropdown. After scraping the first village from that, it should select the second village and so on. When all the villages of that mandal are scraped, it should select the second mandal. And that goes on for **all the villages in all the mandals in all the districts**. The code was inspired from this repository: [github repo](https://github.com/thayton/icds/blob/master/v1.scraper.py)

Problem:
After selecting the first district name, the code halts and throws a `TimeoutException` without selecting the mandal name.

Code link [code](https://github.com/VineetChaurasiya/scraping_scripts/blob/master/telangana_scrape.py)

Also, when I comment out the mandal_select_updated and village_select_updated functions it works but then it skips some mandals and villages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have provided more details, check if that makes the question more understandable?